# How do I change time in ubuntu from local to UTC

Tags: time, timezone

```
ianjoh@ausjenkins0:~$ date
Mon Mar  6 03:34:57 PST 2017
ianjoh@ausjenkins0:~$ timedatectl
      Local time: Mon 2017-03-06 03:35:05 PST
  Universal time: Mon 2017-03-06 11:35:05 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2017-03-06 11:35:06
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
ianjoh@ausjenkins0:~$
```

I want the system time to be the Universal/RTC time but can't figure it out. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timedatectl` command like so

`sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`